# how to convert 2d array to objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

i have this kind of array objects:

```
[
 {
 "abc": [
  {
    "abc def": [
      "sdf/sdf",
      "qwe/er",
      "kjf/er",
      "0/1",
      "df/ff",
      "kkf/iei",
     ]
   }
  ]
 },
 "bcd": [
  {
    "as df": [
      "fd/f",
      "qwe/er",
      "kjf/er",
      "0/1",
      "df/ff",
      "kkf/iei",
     ]
   }
  ]
 },
 "fd": [
  {
    "fdf ff": [
      "sdf/sdf",
      "qwe/er",
      "kjf/er",
      "0/1",
      "df/ff",
      "kkf/iei",
     ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

to put it simply, that is an array of objects, where the objects will be inside of the array and become the index of the array. but, i want the array gone, so it will become pure object lists. so i want to convert it into something like this

```
 {
  "abc":
  {
    "abc def": [
      "sdf/sdf",
      "qwe/er",
      "kjf/er",
      "0/1",
      "df/ff",
      "kkf/iei",
     ]
   },
  "bcd":
  {
    "abc def": [
      "sdf/sdf",
      "qwe/er",
      "kjf/er",
      "0/1",
      "df/ff",
      "kkf/iei",
     ]
   },
  "fd":
  {
    "abc def": [
      "sdf/sdf",
      "qwe/er",
      "kjf/er",
      "0/1",
      "df/ff",
      "kkf/iei",
     ]
   }
  }
```

I have tried using flatmap but it does not work. can someone help me how to do this. answer is appreciated. many thanks

Comment: it looks like you're trying to extract the first value of an array?

Comment: something like that, i actually have lists of objects inside of the array, i want to convert the array to only have lists of object instead of putting it inside of the array

Comment: You should improve the quality of your question. "Something like that" is pretty useless to us if you need to solve an explicit problem. Also, that data structure has a problem with the closing brackets and gives an error.

Comment: i have edited just know

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
const a = [{"abc": [{"abc def": ["sdf/sdf", "qwe/er", "kjf/er", "0/1", "df/ff", "kkf/iei"] } ] }];    
a.reduce((obj, item) => { const key = Object.keys(item)[0]; const first_value = item[key][0]; return {[key]: first_value}}, {})
```

Comment: thank you for answering. but, this only works for the first value, how about the other objects